# Will a change from MyISAM to InnoDB require SQL query changes in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am planning to change some large `MyISAM` tables in my MySQL database into `InnoDB`.

This is because I am having performance problems where large and complex updates (updating a few million rows in one go) are stopping users from concurrently accessing that tables.

I understand that if I convert the table to InnoDB then the writes/updates will cause row locking rather than table locking.

If I do this, **Will have have to review all my `SQL selects/insert statements`, and my stored procedures, and make any changes due to the engine change, or will they all 'just work'?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need to change any `SQL statements and SP's`, They should work as they were before.

You need to keep in mind some points

1. If you have MySQL version 5.5 or below and you have `FULL TEXT index` on Table then this is a issue, `InnoDB` doesn't support FULL TEXT index up to MySQL 5.5, They are supported in `MySQL 5.6` and above.
2. If you have `Spatial Indexes` on table, They are yet not supported in `InnoDB` engine

There are a lot of other points that you should keep in mind are, Please must have a look at some great links which suggest what are various things you should consider in migrating table from MyISAM to InnoDB

1. [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM.?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam)
2. [How do you tune MySQL for a heavy InnoDB workload. ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-do-you-tune-mysql-for-a-heavy-innodb-workload)
3. [Should I move to InnoDB during a planned migration. ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/should-i-move-to-innodb-during-a-planned-migration)
4. [Online conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5119/rows-missing-after-online-conversion-from-myisam-to-innodb)
5. [Converting Tables from MyISAM to InnoDB.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)